# Is there any working zk-snark implementation (even if experimental) among the existing Ethereum clients?

Tags: clients, zksnark

I've asked that question on some places, got a few answers but I'm still missing the bigger piece. I'd like to experiment with zk-snarks. In particular, I'd like to be able to do something similar to [this](https://media.consensys.net/introduction-to-zksnarks-with-examples-3283b554fc3b) tutorial, i.e., write a program to prove some computation based on a pair of public and secret values, such as:

```
function senderFunction(x, w) {
  return (
    w.senderBalanceBefore > w.value &&
    sha256(w.value) == x.hashValue &&
    sha256(w.senderBalanceBefore) == x.hashSenderBalanceBefore &&
    sha256(w.senderBalanceBefore - w.value) == x.hashSenderBalanceAfter
  )
}
var proof = zksnarkprove(
    confTxSenderPk,
    senderFunction,
    [hashSenderBalanceBefore, hashSenderBalanceAfter, hashValue],
    [senderBalanceBefore, senderBalanceAfter, hashValue]);
```

And then be able to verify the correctness of this computation without knowing `w` from inside an Ethereum contract, for example:

```
zksnarkverify(
    confTxSenderVk, 
    [hashSenderBalanceBefore, hashSenderBalanceAfter, hashValue],
    zkProofSender)
```

Is there anything already implemented that allows me to experiment with this usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find the zksnarks solidity code:

https://gist.github.com/chriseth/f9be9d9391efc5beb9704255a8e2989d

[The transaction can be seen on Etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x15e7f5ad316807ba16fe669a07137a5148973235738ac424d5b70f89ae7625e3) and was made on the testnet.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is a fairly dumb one, as I've only had a look around in the code, and I haven't looked into zk-SNARKs properly yet, so apologies in advance if it's no help.

The `cpp-ethereum` implementation contains the [`libdevcrypto`](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/tree/8f8edab793a87a47d7df2b95129cdcd4ef1ebd3a/libdevcrypto) library, which itself contains [`LibSnark.cpp`](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/8f8edab793a87a47d7df2b95129cdcd4ef1ebd3a/libdevcrypto/LibSnark.cpp). This seems to be built into a separate project with its own [`cmake`](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/8f8edab793a87a47d7df2b95129cdcd4ef1ebd3a/cmake/ProjectSnark.cmake) file, and there's a set of associated [unit test files](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/e2c2a0a2f18dd6847510f16883cace6884fead30/test/unittests/libdevcrypto/LibSnark.cpp). There doesn't seem to be anything in any of the other clients (including Parity).

The test file I linked to contains this comment, which would imply *something* is working at least...

> // This verifies a full zkSNARK proof. Let's see if this hocus-pocus
>   actually works...

Comment: It's in the development pipeline, and will likely be there through 2017.

Comment: @Richard please can you advise, how to use in my smart contact? Do I need any extra setup for this?